Kotlin - how can I create a list of numbers between a range and stepped by a certain value
In Kotlin, I'm trying to create a val with a list of numbers within a specific range, incremented by 1.5.  How can I do this?  I've tried the below, but I'm getting an error with "step".
val heightOptionsInCm: List<Double> = (92.00..214.50 step 1.5).toList()

You can use List(82) { 92 + it * 1.5 } or, if you need a function, fun list(start: Double, end: Double, step: Double) = List(ceil((end - start) / step).toInt()) { start + it * step }
